# Error 'WindowsFormsApplication1.Form1.Delobj' is a 'type', which is not valid in the given context

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

This is my code:

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public delegate void Delobj();
        Delobj obj;

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form2 obj2 = new Form2();
            obj2.Show();
            Form3 obj3 = new Form3();
            obj3.Show();
            Delobj += obj2.getmessage();
            Delobj += obj3.getmessage();    
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            obj.Invoke();
        }
    }
}
```

I get this error:

> Error 1   'WindowsFormsApplication1.Form1.Delobj' is a 'type', which is not valid in the given context    E:\net\projects\WindowsFormsApplication1\WindowsFormsApplication1\Form1.cs  33  13  WindowsFormsApplication1

Answer (score 1):

`Delobj` is the type of the delegate. The actual instance variable of type `Delobj` that you need to set to a valid void method accepting no parameters is called `obj`

```
  obj += obj2.getmessage();
  obj += obj3.getmessage();
```